# What is the use of square brackets ([]) when constructing an object in C#

Tags: c#, object-initialization

I stumbled across a line of code I have never seen. Given this code:

```
public NodeItem (bool isWall, Vector2 pos, int x, int y)
{
    this.isWall = isWall;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

What is the purpose/use of the square brackets in this code?

```
private NodeItem[,] map;

map = new NodeItem[width, height];
```

Comment: [Multidimensional Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: So basically with the NodeItem[,] you are creating an 2d array of NodeItems (not yet initialized). so you create an arrays within a array filled with NodeItems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an object. When you're using square brackets, you're declaring an **array** (unlike C and C++, you don't specify the numbers of elements. Instead, you do this when you initialize the array with a `new` statement, such as `new <Type>[<itemsNumber>]`).

An array is a set of objects (which any object should be initialized) - any **array element** (the term for a single item of a given array) contains the object's default value - 0 for numbers, `null` for reference types and pointers, etc.

But when you're declaring an array, you save you a place in the memory to store the array elements (arrays are reference types, so they are stored in the heap).

When you're using a comma inside an array declaration, you're declaring a **multidimensional array**. This is a matrix (for 2D array; it may be 3D, 4D, etc.). To access an array element, you specify in the square brackets all the indexes, separated by commas.

For more details about arrays in C# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/, and about multidimensional arrays - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays.

Comment: So I have an array with "width-rows" and "height-columns"... thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

In c#, `x[]` is an array of type `x`. `x[,]` is a two-dimensional array (and naturally, `x[,,]` is a three-dimensional array and so on).

So - `private NodeItem[,] map;` is declaring a field that is a two-dimensional array of `NodeItem`, named `map`.

The line after that - `map = new NodeItem[width, height];` initialize the array - so it now contains `width * height` references to `NodeItem`, all implicitly initialized to `default(NodeItem)` - `null` for reference types, and whatever default value for value types.

For further reading, [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) And [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)